# Printing the pid of just started process before its output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ssh

I am controlling a remote Linux machine via SSH, I need to be able to know the pid of a process while it is running and its exit status after the run

My attempt has been to issue this command via SSH

> my_cmd & echo $!; wait $!; echo $?;

The output is thus the following, exactly what I need:

```
pid
...stdout...
exit_status
```

Now sometimes it happens that apparently the command is too fast, so I get something like:

```
...stdout...
pid
exit_status
```

Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a background program then it is an independent process and it is necessary to do some synchronization if an output in a defined order is required. But this particular can be solved easily via exec and additional shell script:

First script, let say `start`:

```
#!/bin/bash
start2 &
wait $!
echo $?
```

second script `start2`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $$
exec my_cmd
```

Now the first script starts the second one and waits for result. And the second script prints own pid and then execs the program which will run with the same pid as the second script.

Comment: Thanks! I used your idea and modified it a bit to write `bash -c 'echo $$; exec  my_cmd ' ; echo $?`. It is working well so far, I wonder if it is also a stable solution

Comment: Seems ok but I guess the `echo $?` will not be called because the shell calls the exec before. So I think the printouts will have corrected order but the result will not be printed. Nevertheless I did not test it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you use & you are invoking a background process with its output to stdout as you exemplified... And that's the point. Your process execution and stdout printing is happening faster than pid query and printing and so on.... So what I recommend you is to redirect stdout to a /tmp/tempfile and then print it exactly when you need the output to be printed.... Example:

`$ o=/tmp/_o; your_cmd 1>$o 2>$o & echo "pid is $!"; wait $!; r=$?; cat $o; echo "return is $r"; rm -f $o`

first we set output variable 'o' to '/tmp/_o' temporary file

then we run your_cmd redirecting all output (1 and 2 which means stdout and stderr) to $o (which points to /tmp/_o).

then we show the pid

then we wait pid

then we set return var 'r' (to show it after output)

then we concatenate the output, showing it for you as you wish..

then we show the return

then we remove the tempfile 'o'..

Hope this way works for your case..
Hope you don't think it's too complex.
Hope someone to answer a simple way to do workaround this for you..